# Enable Hot/Remove CPU and RAM

Tags: vmware, vmware-server

How do I enable CPU hot add and Remove for this virtual machine option?Are they any OS specific configuration required or NUMA architecture is required?

[image: Enable Hot/Remove CPU and RAM]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is specific.

**Linux**: Newer Linux kernels have support for CPU hot add and CPU hot remove. To verify this, check the documentation for your Linux distribution in the documentation directory of the distribution source code. The documentation contains directions for special boot time switches related to CPU Hot Plug, as well as how to dynamically bring CPUs on and offline.

**Windows**: Windows Server 2012 (Standard and Datacenter Edition) and Windows Server 2008 Datacenter Edition support CPU hot add, but not CPU hot remove.

**Note**: Windows Server 2008 Standard and Enterprise Editions do not support CPU hot add.

Check and conform the virtual machine's are using hardware version 7 or later.

For information regarding hot add Refer this links.

[VMware KB](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2020993)

[Hot Plug Settings](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/configuring_virtual_machines/t_change_cpu_hotplug_settings.html)

Comment: I'm agree with comment,but how can I enable CPU hot plug option -> enable CPU host add and remove for this virtual machine.